# Windows 10 Black Screen and Spring Tools Suite?

Tags: windows-10, spring-tool-suite

I just got a new laptop that came with Windows 10 Operating System. I'm trying to setup workspaces that use [Spring Tools Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) on my system. I've tried both the 4.5.2 and 4.6 versions of STS from the site.

The problem I'm encountering is that if I leave STS open for a period of time or if I try to perform certain operations such as a Run Configuration I will just see a black screen and am unable to do anything.

Anytime I see the black screen the only common thing is that I had STS open, so my assumption is that the issue may relate to STS. I could be completely wrong and this be unrelated to STS entirely but I can only reproduce the problem when STS has been open.

Two Questions, can anyone please provide any insight as my searches online aren't providing any resolution
1. Any special configuration others have run into for Windows 10 and STS? 
2. If I get the black screen, how can I recover other than a hard power off, others experience with this?

Thanks for your input

Comment: I do have this setup on a Windows 7 machine without any problems

Comment: can you check whether this is related to Windows 10 or specific to your machine? Do you have another Windows 10 machine somewhere near you to try?

Comment: May be isolated to just this machine. An update of NIVIDIA driver and a lower resolution seems to possibly have fixed this.

Comment: I was wrong, this issue still continues to happen :(. What setup does anyone running Windows 10 and STS have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get past this issue by updating a number of drivers on my machine from Dell support page. I use a **Dell Precision 5510** and was able to go to Dell support site and search for drivers for my machine.

I did the following Steps to fix my Precision 5510

1. Go to [Dell Support Page](http://www.dell.com/support/home)
2. Click on Support
3. Click on Drivers and Downloads
4. Click on tab 'Find it myself' so you can select drivers you want
5. Scroll to bottom of the page and click on the line highlighted in blue that reads, Browse all drivers for Precision 5510
6. In list of drivers choose Chipset drivers
7. There may be other drivers that you need to install but adding the following fixed my issues
8. Be sure to restart your machine after install/update of each driver

   - Basic Input/Output System (BIOS)
   - Intel(R) Thunderbol 3 Controller Driver
   - Install the Firmware Update
   - Realtek USB GBE Ethernet Controller Driver
   - Realtek USB Audio Driver
   - Patch for the USB audio/mouse issue

Combination of the above or one of the drivers fixed my issue, I'm not certain which one Spring Tools depended on but it does not crash to a black screen now after updating these drivers.